# How to prompt for $args when missing

Tags: powershell, args

My script:

```
$computername=$args[0]
if ($args -eq $null) { $computername = Read-Host "enter computer name" }
Get-ADComputer -Id $computername -Properties * | select name,description
```

If I pass the argument with the script i.e.:

```
get-ComputerName.ps1 computer01
```

it works fine. However if I skip the computer I want it to prompt me but instead I'm getting this error:

```
Get-ADComputer : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument
is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the
command again.
At U:\get-ADComputer-assigned-user.ps1:9 char:20
+ Get-ADComputer -Id $computername -Properties * | select name,description
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer
```

I cannot figure out how to make it work.

Comment: read the [advanced function help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847806.aspx) and use a mandatory parameter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use the [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) `$args`, but define a specific mandatory parameter for the computername:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
  [string]$ComputerName
)

Get-ADComputer -Id $ComputerName -Properties * | Select-Object Name, Description
```

That will allow you to run your script like this:

```
./Get-ComputerName.ps1 -ComputerName computer01
```

or like this:

```
./Get-ComputerName.ps1 computer01
```

If the parameter is missing you'll be prompted for it:

```
PS C:\> ./Get-ComputerName.ps1

cmdlet test.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
ComputerName: _
```

If you want the script to throw an error instead of prompting for a missing parameter you could do it like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=0)]
  [string]$ComputerName = $(throw 'Parameter missing!')
)

Get-ADComputer -Id $ComputerName -Properties * | Select-Object Name, Description
```

[Check](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847829.aspx) [the](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847806.aspx) [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx) for further information about parameter handling in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that $args will always be there, so ($args -eq $null) will always be false. To see if $args is empty you can do

```
if ($args.Length -eq 0)
```